# Doxygen Not Documenting c++ Source Files

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I've set the `INPUT` field to my source directory, and my `FILE_PATTERNS` field contains all the names of my source files. I've tried explicitly naming the sources and using wildcards, and it only generates documentation for my header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `EXTRACT_ALL` field to "YES" fixes this.